# Match and delete array item in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have `NSMutableDictionary` and I want to **delete** and refresh my tableview inside where `code` value is equal to `deletecode`.

> How can I do it? , My codes under below.

```
var myCells = [NSMutableDictionary]()
myCells = [["isExpanded" : false,
            "isVisible" : true,
            "additionalRows" : 7,
            "code" : "Flex1"
           ],
           [ "isExpanded" : false,
             "isVisible" : true,
             "additionalRows" : 7,
             "code" : "Flex3"
           ],
           [ "isExpanded" : false,
             "isVisible" : true,
             "additionalRows" : 7,
             "code" : "Flex4"
           ]]

 let deletecode = "Flex1"

 if let indexOfA = myCells.flatMap({$0["\(deletecode))"]}).last {
     self.tableView.beginUpdates()
     self.myCells.remove(at: indexOfA as! Int)
     self.tableView.endUpdates()
     self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

My code part 2

```
myCells = myCells.filter { (element) -> Bool in
        if let code = element["additionalRows"] as? String {
            if code != "7" {

            }else {

                let fetchRequestf                = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Match")
                let predicatek = NSPredicate (format:"code = %@",(element["code"] as? String)!)
                fetchRequestf.predicate = predicatek

                do {
                    let getSett = try context.fetch(fetchRequestf) as! [Match]

                    if (getSett.count > 0) {

                        if (getSett[0].show == false){

                            let deletecode = getSett[0].code

                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            myCells = myCells.filter { (element) -> Bool in
                                if let code = element["code"] as? String {
                                    return code != deletecode
                                }
                                return true
                            }

                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }


                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        return true

    }
```

Comment: You can't set up a fetch request inside the filter closure.  The closure will be called each element in the array.  You need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `filter` your array:

```
myCells = myCells.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    if let code = element["code"] as? String {
        return code != deletecode
    }
    return true
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: yeah Paul when I use this codes in viewDidLoad working but when my tableview didSelectRowAt my array return again first how can I fix it ?

Comment: In `didSelectRowAt` don't you know the index path that you want to delete, or are you deleting from some other table based on the selection?

Comment: I added my My code part 2 you can see there my all codes,  if in my Coredata inside Match table items show != true I need to remove them inside my myCells array and I don't want to show them inside my tableview

Comment: and that part2 codes  before last return true myCells.count gives = 10 true but after shows in my tableview 19 , I think doesn't delete items in array maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

The first line is unnecessary - you can just instead write

```
var myCells = [items]
```

When you create an array as **var** it will be mutable.

Instead of **flatMap** use **index(of:)**

Your code can look like this:

```
myCells.index{$0["code"] == "Flex4"}
```